# Error HH700 during Contract deploment

Tags: contract-deployment

[image]
Compiled 1 Solidity file successfully
TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="deployed", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.6.1)
at makeError (D:\d-drive 3.0\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:670:21)
at assert (D:\d-drive 3.0\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:694:25)
at assertArgument (D:\d-drive 3.0\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:706:5)
at Interface.getFunctionName (D:\d-drive 3.0\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\interface.ts:542:23)
at buildWrappedMethod (D:\d-drive 3.0\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:334:34)
at BaseContract.getFunction (D:\d-drive 3.0\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:849:22)
at Object.get (D:\d-drive 3.0\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:747:39)
at main (D:\d-drive 3.0\scripts\deploy.js:7:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
argument: 'key',
value: 'deployed'
}

and my contract code is:
[image]

Please Help! I have tried almost everything camelcase method , not including .sol in getcontractfactory.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `await upload.deployed` from your script file.

Then try again.

Comment: Thankyou for that gesture ,  but it still not compiled it is showing error HH700: Artifact for contract "Upload" not found.

Comment: There can be 2 reasons for this. 

1. You are putting the wrong name of the contract in getContractFactory(). Check your "Upload" contract correct name. Also check if you are using correct Uppercase or Lowercase.


2. If the above does not resolve, clean the artifacts folder by typing
```npx hardhat clean```. Now try to run the deploy script again.